# last day of last month date expression in ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I have to create a derived column to upload a date in OLEDB destination because my source file doesn't contain this date. The date i want to get through derived column is last day of last month. Does anyone know how to get it?

Comment: What do you mean by last day of last month? Do you mean of current month?

Comment: Hi Haidi, the end result i want to upload is 2017-05-31. i.e last day of last month. How to write expression to get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following expression, just substract the current day from the current date using `DATEADD` Function.

```
DATEADD("d", -DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE())
```

If you want to remove time you have two choices:

1. convert to string

   ```
   LEFT((DT_STR,50,1252)DATEADD("d", -DAY(GETDATE()),GETDATE()),10)
   ```
2. convert to string then to date (it will generate time 12:00 AM)

   ```
   (DT_DATE)LEFT((DT_STR,50,1252)DATEADD("d", -DAY(GETDATE()),GETDATE()),10)
   ```

Comment: Hi Hadi, I only want "2017-05-31" not hh:MM:ss PM . How to get that?

Comment: @Kate I updated my answer and still waiting for a reply

Comment: LEFT((DT_STR,50,1252)DATEADD("d", -DAY(GETDATE()),GETDATE()),10) works for me thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way if you don't need time is :

```
(DT_DBDATE)(DATEADD("d",-DAY(GETDATE()),GETDATE()))
```